# Display the total CPU usage in percentage in the notification bar on Android

Tags: android, system-monitor

I'm looking for an Android application that can display the total CPU usage in percentage in the notification bar.

The closest I could find so far is [CPU stats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.takke.cpustats) (gratis) but it doesn't show a percentage, only some plot:

[image]

Comment: Looks like this app is open-sourced, perhaps you can put a feature request on [their GitHub repo](https://github.com/takke/cpustats/issues).